# Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.1 organizer reads my iPhone with a yellow dot?

Tags: testing, xcode4.2, ios5.1, organizer

SO I have Xcode 4.2 and my iPhone 4S is running iOS 5.1 . I have an app that I want to test out in my iPhone but when I connect my iPhone to my Mac it reads the device with the Provisioning Profile and everything, but it displays a yellow dot next to the device (iPhone) list. All this is in the  Organizer Window.

I also have an App ID. I just need help on how to fix the yellow dot so It can change to a green dot?

Comment: Why does it say the "yellow dot" is there?

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked for me
First I ran the project in xcode 3.2.5 and the project ran on iOS 5.1!!!! *Later i disconnected the device and again ran the project on xcode 4.2* on snow leopard and it started working with out nay problem.Dont know how this worked
I was having snow leopard and old xcode 3.2.5